# how to add row count to the first line of an existing file

Tags: linux, shell, unix, scripting

I need to add row counts to a file that already has a line and I need to add the row counts to the same line.
Input: input: zzzzzzzzzzzzz zzz zzz PE 1 27 09 22 000000 - this comes from Informatica

Output(which I need): zzzzzzzzzzzzz zzz zzz PE 1 27 09 22 000000 1 00000 00000 2 3 6 00000
(where 1,2,3,6 are the row counts)

I tried to use:

```
wc -l ${V_EACH_FILE} | cut -d '' -f1 >> file.dat
```

but I am getting output like

```
zzzzzzzzzzzzz zzz zzz PE 1 27 09 22 000000

    1
    2 
    3
    6
```

can anyone please tell me how to do it?

Comment: Try something like: `wc -l ${V_EACH_FILE} | cut -d '' -f1 | xargs -n 1 >> file.dat` its not tested since there are no samples given in your question. OR if you could post samples of input and expected output in your question it will make it more clear, thank you.

Comment: I need to append the count to the first line which comes from Informatica. 
like: abcd    rye   efiewhf  1 2 3 6

Comment: Would like to request you to add sample of **input** and expected **output** in your question to make it more clear, thank you.

Comment: input: zzzzzzzzzzzzz zzz zzz PE 1 27 09 22 000000 - this comes from Informatica
output:  zzzzzzzzzzzzz zzz zzz PE 1 27 09 22 000000 1 00000 00000 2 3 6 00000   
 (where 1,2,3,6 are the row counts)

Comment: Please edit your question with the data (proper formatting!) and the complete task at hand. [so] is a site dedicated to single problems, not iterative approaches to multi-layered tasks.

Answer (score 0):

I have my doubts regarding your `cut` invocations output ... but the following awk does what you're asking.

```
wc -l ${V_EACH_FILE} | awk '{printf "%s ", $1}' >> file.dat
```

Comment: will this append to the existing line or will a new line be created? Because I need to append to a line which comes from informatica

Comment: If the existing file has a trailing new line it won't replace it - but then that wasn't part of your question.

Comment: There is only one line. and the row count should get appended to the same line

Comment: @nischithashekar - again: this has nothing to do with your original question. And "there is only one line" means fairly little, one line can still have a newline / carriage return at the end.  What does `od -a`  say about the file you'd like to attach to? Is the last character a `sp`?

Comment: @nischithashekar if I run the above command repeatedly, starting with a non-existing file.dat, all output stays on one line. If I start with a file that has a single line with a trailing carriage return the new data will appear in a second line, and all subsequent calls will be appended to that.

Comment: is there any way to add row counts to the same line?

Comment: Sure ... `printf "%s" "$(< file.dat)" > tmp && mv tmp file.dat` and then run the above.

Comment: Have you understood by now that the problem is not w/ the command above but with the output from informatica, and that you need to sanitise *THAT* before appending it to it? @nischithashekar ?